# In CrafterCMS, what else is required to setup the workflow?

Tags: email, configuration, content-management-system, workflow, crafter-cms

In **CrafterCMS**, I setup my local environment to enable the **workflow** by following these guides:

1. Configure workflow notifications
   http://docs.craftercms.org/en/2.5/site-administrators/studio/configure-notifications.html?highlight=workflow
2. Setup email configuration
   http://docs.craftercms.org/en/2.5/system-administrators/tmp/installation-guides/configure.html?highlight=workflow
3. add notificationService.v2.enable=true
   http://docs.craftercms.org/en/2.5/projects/studio/configuration/notifications.html?highlight=notification

but when I'm creating, editing or publishing a component the email is not sent. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing to check: 
The content you are publishing must be in workflow in order for an email to be sent.  The out of the box workflow configuration is a simple workflow whereby Admins can simply publish, while authors must submit content for approval.

In order for you to receive an email, you must submit content as an author. This action will start a workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that you are pointed to a proper SMTP server and port?  Check to see

```
TOMCAT/shared/classes/crafter/cstudio/extension/server-config.properties¶
crafter.studio.mail.host=smtp.mail.com
crafter.studio.mail.port=25
```

Check the mail log on the server to see if the application is attempting to send mail through the server.